# SQFlite delete not working for a single row item

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

```
// Creating/opening the database
Future<Database> _getDatabase() async {
  final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
  final db = await sql.openDatabase(
    path.join(dbPath, 'my_list_flutter.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE user_list(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, quantity INT, unit TEXT, cat_title TEXT)');
    },
    version: 1,
  );
  return db;
}
```

Above I am creating/opening database

Below is for deleting an item

```
 void deleteItem(GroceryItem item) async {
    final id = item.id;
    final db = await _getDatabase();
    final count =
        await db.rawDelete('DELETE FROM user_list WHERE id = ?', [id]);

    print(count);
    state = state.where((e) => e != item).toList();
  }
}
```

But it is not deleting from database.
value of count is coming 0 i.e zero rows affected....

Please help

I also tried following code

```
final count = db.delete('user_list' , where : 'id = ?' , whereArgs : [id]);
```

Still same result...

Dont know what to do.

Comment: Have you tried *fetching* a row with that id to make sure it's even in the database?

Comment: fetch row with id and then print it and then delete with this id .